# How do I plot data from excel file with legends picking the column heading?

Tags: plotting, import, dataset

I have my data on an excel file (with five columns and 15 rows) and would like to import the file into mathematica and then:
(a). Plot column 1 against column 3
(b). Plot column 1 against column 2, 3, 4 and 5 (multiple curves)
However, I would like the legend labels to be picked directly form the column heading (y1, y2, y3, y4). I would appreciate comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an excel file with 5 columns and 15 rows:

```
headers = ToString /@ {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5};
values = SortBy[RandomInteger[99, {15, 5}], First];
Export["example.xlsx", Join[{headers}, values]];
```

Import the excel file and take its first part:

```
importeddata = Import["example.xlsx"][[1]];
Grid[importeddata]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[importeddata[[2 ;;, {1, 3}]] , Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[importeddata[[1, {3}]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[importeddata[[2 ;;, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3, 4, 5}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[importeddata[[1, {2, 3, 4, 5}]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or define a function that takes as input a dataset and columns to plot:

```
lpF[data_, cols_] := ListPlot[data[[2 ;;, {1, #}]] & /@ cols, Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[data[[1, cols]]]];

lpF[importeddata, {2, 3, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** As noted by @rcollyer in the comments, in version 10 and later versions, you can transform your data using

```
transformF[data_, cols_]:=<|Map[#[[1, 2]]->#[[2 ;;]]&]@ Map[data[[All, {1, #}]] &]@cols|>;
```

and get the same result without having to use the option `PlotLegends`:

```
ListPlot[transformF[importeddata, {2,3,5}], Joined->True, PlotMarkers->Automatic]
```

Comment: There are several simplifications that can be had. Don't bother with `LineLegend`, it's the default, use `data[[1, cols]]` directly. Better yet, convert your data to this form `<|Map[#[[1, 2]] -> #[[2 ;;]] &]@
  Map[data[[All, {1, #}]] &]@cols|>`, then you don't need to specify `PlotLegends` at all. :)

Comment: @rcollyer, thank you. In version 9, using `data[[1, cols]]` without the `LineLegend` wrapper gives only the markers without the lines in legend.

Comment: In v9, it looks like it isn't picking up the `Joined -> True` which it does in later versions, but you can swap in `ListLinePlot` and the default legend is `LineLegend`. So, the list form would work. Also, if you are using v9, neither `Association`s nor the operator form of `Map` are present. So,  `transformF` won't work unless you have v10.

Comment: `Joined` was formerly `PlotJoined` in earlier versions

Comment: @george2079 in v9, where `PlotLegends` was implemented, `PlotJoined` is no longer listed among the options for `ListPlot` nor does it work. Although, it was still listed as a symbol.

Comment: @kglr, what is the significance of "2" in the code section "importeddata[[2 ;;, {1, 3}]]"? Thank you once again!

Comment: @Dean, `2;;` refers to row indices from the second to the last (we need this to remove the header row).

Comment: @kglr, thank you. Season's greetings to you.

Comment: To you too @Dean.

Comment: @kglr, sorry I have to bother you once again. Assuming I now have only columns y1,y2,y3,y4 and I wish to have two curves (y3 vs y1 and y4 vs y2), what modifications do you suggest I make to "ListPlot[importeddata[[2 ;;, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3, 4, 5}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[importeddata[[1, {2, 3, 4, 5}]]]]" to achieve this?

Comment: @Dean, try `ListPlot[importeddata[[2 ;;,#]] & /@ {{3,1},{4,2}}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Row/@Partition[importeddata[[1, {3,1,4,2}]],2]]]`

Comment: @kglr, worked like a charm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question he has an "x" column and a bunch of "y" columns:

make an example:

```
header = {"x", "sin", "cos"};
x = Range[0, 2 Pi, 1/100];
values = Transpose@{x, Sin[x], Cos[x]};
Export["example.xlsx", Join[{headers}, values]];
Clear[header, x]
```

read it back:

```
{header, data} = Through[{First, Rest}@Import["example.xlsx"][[1]]];
{x, y} = Through[{First, Rest}@Transpose[data]];
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, #}] & /@ y, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> header[[2 ;;]]]
```

[image]

sometimes its convenient to actually copy the x vals and associate with each y column:

```
ydata = Transpose[{x, #}] & /@ y;
ynames = header[[2 ;;]];
```

then you can just do:

```
ListPlot[ydata, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> ynames ]
```

> same plot

Comment: Wao! you guys are excellent. @kglr, george2079 and rcollyer, thank you.