# Plotting long lists of data using Mathematica

Tags: plotting

Say I have Column 1 as my independent variable on x-axis, and Columns 2,3,4,5 as dependent variables which I want to plot against x in the same graph. I have this data entered in an Excel sheet (Consider the "Horizon is 1" part of the "Volume_vs_E" spreadsheet in [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DZDE1UpFz7rsT-Oe24-HuQ09gHaZmI57/view?usp=sharing)). I now want to plot this data using Mathematica.

What I want to do exactly is as follows:

1. I want to copy paste these columns from Excel to a Mathematica notebook.
2. After doing that, I want to plot points in columns 2,3,4,5 vs column 1 using different colors by a curve interpolating between them. It would be nice to get an approximate interpolating function for this curve.

P.S. I am a beginner in Mathematica. Answers will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: What you can do is directly import an excel file into Mathematica. For example if you have your excel file in the same directory as your Mathematica notebook you can use: `data=Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "data.xlsx"];`. You will then get a List of data that you can plot with standard functions in Mathematica such as ListPlot etc.

Comment: @Dunlop Thank you very much. That helped.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140154/3066) may of help to you.